# Java error: Bad version number in .class file error

Tags: java, jar

I've seen other questions relating to this exact error, but they don't seem to help at all.

I'm coding an app to run on a Linux system (CentOS if I'm not mistaken), which has Java 1.5 version. I am currently editing the program on my Eclipse IDE on my Mac OSX system which has Java 1.6.

I compiled the project into a runnable .JAR file. When prompted with the option of what to do with the libraries in Eclipse, I choose "extract selected packages into .JAR file".

I know Eclipse has its own compiler, so in the project settings I changed the target compiler to Java 1.5 and rebuilt. And then repackaged the runnable jar file.

However, when running the .JAR file with "java -jar file.jar" on the target machine, I still get the aforementioned "Bad version number" error.

Can somebody help?

Full error is:

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

I am using only using one external library, sun-javamail.

Thank you

Comment: Please print the full error.  I have two ideas as to what your issue is but I'm not entirely sure atm.

Comment: Thank you. Will do in a few minutes.

Comment: *"When prompted with the option of what to do with the libraries"*  What libraries?  And are you recompiling them as well, or just putting the classes into the final Jar?

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right. Using the library sun-javamail, already compiled as a library jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either:

- haven't recompiled everything with -target 1.5
- haven't redeployed everything
- are using third party JARs compiled for 1.6. The class named in the exception will tell you that.

Comment: This was the problem. It appears I was using the javamail library, compiled for 1.6, in a program for a 1.5 target. I haven't been able to find a replacement yet though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run javap command on class file and check exact version of JDK for which it was complied.

For example:

```
C:\>javap -verbose Main
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "Main.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
...
```

Following is the mapping between major version and jdk

```
MajorVersion     JDK
51      J2SE 7
50      J2SE 6.0
49      J2SE 5.0
```

Reference: [Class file format](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-class-file-format-revealed/)